# What I'm doing wrong in display this table?

Tags: html, html-table

Probably this is a stupid thing, but I don't see it. What is the problem?

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="search" method="get">
    <input>
    <input name="action" value="search" type="submit">
</form>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <th>
        <td>Name</td>

    </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>Smith        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Smith2        </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The "Smiths" are not displayed under the "Name" cell.

Comment: You should probably describe what you want this code to do as opposed to what it is doing right now. Just having this code is not sufficient.

Comment: Man, I don't believe how fast you guys respond. I don't believe it. Forget about the other forums. StackoverFLow is the best.

Comment: Don't thank me. Pay Joel Spolsky. :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

th tags are "table headers", you need to place them inside tr's, "table rows".

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<th>
  <td>Name</td>
</th>
```

Replace with:

```
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are great and fresh post about table explain everything http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/09/rediscovering-html-tables.html must see :)

Answer (score 1):

Th's are the root of your problem. Placing them like so will give you one column like your'e expecting.

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the < td >< /td > inside the < th > and wrap it in a < tr >, you need:

```
<tr>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<thead>

<tr>
<th>
 Name
</th>
</tr>

</thead>
```

TH is just like any column () but with different default properties (bold text, center aligned text). So it has to be nested within a row (  )

Answer (score 1):

Fix your THead element:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```